# global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

Good day!

I am writing a script as follows:

```
var prev = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    dynamicListOne(length, prev);
});

function dynamicListOne(length, prev){
   length++;
   prev = length;
}
```

But prev is always 0.
How can i assign prev=length?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Judging from this snippet (which has errors), the `prev` in `function` is not the same `prev` as the global. You passed a copy of it.

Comment: A function statement without a name is a syntax error. How have you actually defined it?

Comment: how can i pass not the copy of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function takes `prev` as an argument so inside the function the name points to a local variable instead of the global one. Just don't add it as an argument to your function.

And think carefully if you really *really* want a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `prev` variable in your function signature hides the global `prev` variable.  Choose a different name and it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass in prev as a parameter

```
var prev = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    dynamicListOne(length);
    console.log(prev)
});

function(length){
   length++;
   prev = length;
}
```